# When is the Grand Galloping Gala?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In My Little Pony: Firendship is magic, one of the events in the year is the Grand Galloping Gala. In another question someone mentioned that the GGG occured between 'Christmas' and 'Valentines'. Is there a more accurate date than this?

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote please?

Comment: It's not me (check my gravatar), but maybe because MLP is _barely_ SciFi?  I'm happy to see some questions on the show here, and I like the argument about Diskord, but I think it's a bit of a stretch to call it SciFi or Fantasy.

Comment: @Ward then it should be flagged as off topic, and be sorted by a mod.

Comment: Not a downvote, but they don't have christmas OR valentine's day in ponyville/equestria. They DO have Hearts and Hooves day, but I don't recall anything particularly christmasy.

Comment: @Rob I was basing that comment of mine off of someone elses answer/comment else where.

Comment: Maybe they were upset at calling it Great instead of Grand?

Comment: @Ward It is entirely not sci-fi.  It's falls pretty well into the realm of fantasy though.

Comment: They have a holiday called Hearths Warming Eve. It's in the winter and seems close to Christmas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official MLP:FIM [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/MyLittlePony) and [official MLP Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/mylittlepony/photos/a.134316363252476.23944.118429394841173/777275375623235/?type=1), the Grand Galloping Gala is held annually on **New Year's Eve.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Haha, awesome and 1000% canon.

Comment: Excellent. Mwahahaha.....

Comment: @Pureferret - Oh my lord. I'm turning into a brony

Answer (score 4):

Fluttershy mentions that the flowers in Canterlot's private garden are in bloom during the event. The event is outdoors and the weather looked late spring to early summer. It can't be the first day of spring (winter wrap up) or first day of summer (summer sun celebration). It must be located somewhere between those two. The MLP Facebook page puts it on New Years Eve. That only means that NYE should be between winter wrap up and summer sun celebration. No one said Equestria's year was exactly like ours.

Comment: As added info: in Ticket Master, Celestia's message, read by spike, mentions it is on the 21st of then he mumbles. Twilight says 'it's summer' to Fluttershy as she says she is doing 'spring cleaning'. Fluttershy says there are 'flowers that only bloom that night' (of the gala). This episode is right after the opener of season one where they were celebrating the Summer Sun Celebration (the longest day of the year). That puts the GGG and NYE sometime in the summer.

Comment: Also, this is the Science Fiction and FANTASY StackExchange, so I believe MLP is covered under that.

Answer (score 3):

Given available information, it's hard to say. The current season isn't usually shown much outside of the two main seasonal episodes, and The Best Night Ever took place long after those. If we can take the environmental conditions in that episode to be true though, then it would take place in very early spring.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Gala is somewhere around March 20 to April 20 because it says that all the flowers bloom simultaneously and that is when most flowers bloom in the spring.

Comment: Unless you're in the Southern hemisphere. And why is Equestria using the Julian calendar anyways?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack Exchange. Quick note: this sounds more like an opinion rather than a verifiable answer. ("I believe" is often a bad start.) Might I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions here? We're not a typical discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the Facebook post says it's on New Year's Eve, but the signs in the show says it's somewhere in the Summer. If Spike says it's on the 21st of something then it can't be New Year's unless Equestria's months are shorter than ours. However, Twilight says it's summer, and Fluttershy says all the flowers will bloom the night of the Gala. I guess it happens after the longest day of summer (because it happened after the Summer Sun Celebration 1st Episode) but before of during the peak of summer when all the flowers bloom. The longest day of the year is June 21, and the peak of summer is somewhere in late July. Let's say July 20th. Since spike said the 21st, we can assume that the Grand Galloping Gala is on July 21st. Of course that is just a rough estimate, but I think it might be accurate. 1 month is a pretty reasonable amount of time for 1 season worth of episodes to happen.